# Computing kernel matrix in smoothing spline in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, kernel-smoothing, splines

Consider the smoothing spline
$$
\hat f = \arg\min_{f}\sum_{i=1}^n{(y_i-f(x_i))^2} + \lambda \int_0^1{f^{(m)}(x)^2dx}.
$$
It is well-known that the estimate $\hat y_i=\hat f(x_i)$ can be expressed as $\hat y=Kx$ for some $n\times n$ matrix $X$ that depends on $x$ and $\lambda$ only.

**Question**: how can I compute $K$, given $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ and $\lambda$, in MATLAB? I need this kernel matrix for different values of $m$ (e.g., $m=1,2,3$), not only the standard cubic spline.